Stock Samsung Galaxy Note 9 bricked, unable to reinstall software with Odin. Gives an error saying that /data can't be mounted
My Samsung Note 9 bricked itself after I installed an apk theme. Upon trying to reinstall the software, I'm met with an error saying that /data failed to mount.
I have tried clearing the cache and factory resetting in the recovery mode, along with repartitioning and erasing the nand in Odin, but no luck.
The phone is 100% stock and I can't unlock the bootloader as it's a US model.
Is the phone just done for at this point? I haven't found any info that points to me being able to do anything but get a new motherboard.

Was the error message "/data failed to mount" present right from the beginning when your phone made problems or was the error message changing? In general reflashing stock firmware with Odin should be the correct way for device recovery.

Yes, it's present right from the start. It gets to about 3% on the update screen before it pops up. I can flash the BL, AP, and CP files without any issue, but as soon as I try the CSC file that's when the error appears.
